# How to add to a value to a specific 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering the best way to do this in javascript (ES6).

So I have a 2 dimensional array like so:

```
const two_dimensional_array = [
   [33000, 100],
   [33500, 200],
]
```

I now have another 2 dimensional array like so:

```
const another_array = [
 [33500, 1300]
]
```

and I want it to find the the first value from `another_array` in `two_dimensional_array` and then add the 2nd value to it. So the end result of `two_dimensional_array` would be like:

```
const two_dimensional_array = [
   [33000, 100],
   [33500, 1500],
]
```

Comment: You should attempt this yourself first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from `another_array` where the key is the first number of the pair and the value is the second number.
- Using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over `two_dimensional_array` and try to check if there's a number to add (0 otherwise).

```js
const 
  two_dimensional_array = [ [33000, 100], [33500, 200] ],
  another_array = [ [33500, 1300] ];

const map = new Map(another_array);

two_dimensional_array.forEach(arr => arr[1] += map.get(arr[0]) ?? 0);

console.log(two_dimensional_array);
```